# Why isn't inv_sqrt2 defined in the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, constants, std, c++20, inline-variable

C++20 introduces standard library header, *<numbers>*, with definitions in namespace `std::numbers` for math constants such as `sqrt2` and `sqrt3`. It provide inverse values like `inv_sqrt3`, but not `inv_sqrt2`. Why is `inv_sqrt2` missing?

Answer (score 9):

> Why is `inv_sqrt2` missing?

The library defines a minimal set of commonly-used constants as precisely as the type will allow. It can be tricky to express (√3)<sup>-1</sup> without introducing rounding errors, hence `inv_sqrt3`. However, (√2)<sup>-1</sup> can easily be expressed as: `sqrt2 / 2`, so `inv_sqrt2` isn't defined.

Comment: Wouldn't the same reasoning apply to `sqrt3 / 3`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @cigien `sqrt2/2` suffers no loss of precision because division by 2 is exact in IEEE arithmetic. Division by 3 not so much.

Comment: @RaymondChen it might not be exact, but don't IEEE arithmetic rules dictate that it will be accurate to 1 LSB?  I don't see how a hard coded constant could be more accurate.

Comment: @MarkRansom The point is that given `sqrt2` with maximum possible accuracy, you can derive `1/sqrt2` with maximum possible accuracy, since it's just decrementing the exponent by 1.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You round twice in forming the constant and then dividing.  Only one of those is inevitable in representing whatever final value.